# Hosting Ventrilo - license question

Tags: license, ventrilo

I have access to a dedicated server, and I would like to set up a Ventrilo server on it.

I don't plan to profit from this Ventrilo server, but their website is quite vague about the legality of hosting a Ventrilo server (< 1000 slot, mind you) without paying for a license. Licensing looks fairly expensive considering I will never have more than a couple hundred slots in use.

In summary: if I am hosting a Ventrilo server with less than a thousand slots, do I need to pay for a license?

EDIT: Further clarification - I will be offering the server to other people for their own use alongside everyone else. This will be offered for free. I am fairly certain this is okay on a standard, free, server license, but I'd like to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked their license in awhile, but last time I did you were allowed to run their server software as long as you weren't making any money off of it (ie charging people for hosting it). And last time I checked the server only allowed a max of 8 people.

They may have changed it, but Teamspeak allowed unlimited connections under the same pretense (you didn't charge people to use it).

Comment: Latest license still limits to 8 clients, it seems. That's a definite problem. I can set up Teamspeak but Ventrilo is what everyone I've talked to about this seems to prefer.

Comment: You could get some cash together and either pay for a license or purchasing hosting from someone if that is what your fellows prefer. If I were you I would say "put in the cash, or we are using Teamspeak". :).

Answer (score 0):

[Server 3.0 - Public version](http://www.ventrilo.com/purchase.php):

> The public version of the Ventrilo 3.0 server can be used without a license fee, so long as you abide by the terms of the LICENSE. Each of the public servers contains a file named LICENSE and by downloading and running the server you are agreeing to the terms of this license.

As long as you follow the terms of the LICENSE you should be fine.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.</sub>

Comment: The OP complains about the vagueness of the language on the website. Downloading is broken at the moment, and I can't view the LICENSE file, so I came here. Ventrilo is to blame for vagueness and not linking to license directly, but this answer doesn't give any information not available on the website.